# convert row_number() to int in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query where i have used row_number() function. My query is like the following

```
SELECT ID, 
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Position desc) Rank
FROM Tbl
```

Problem is Rank is producing a bigint value. But i want to convert it to an int. How can i do it?

Comment: Use `Convert` or `Cast`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This isn't particularly difficult;

```
SELECT ID, 
CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Position desc) AS INT) Rank
FROM Tbl
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT name, 
cast (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by object_id desc) as int) Rank
FROM sys.objects
```